# How to add blank columns at specific positions in big text file?

Tags: regex, vba, notepad++

I have 200 files with same format and need to edit all in the same way till end of file, I need to add multiple blank (single space) columns starting from 7th row till end of file.

**Actual:**

```
O-XYZ-04           101.0274239.30N692920.64E
```

**Target:**

```
O-XYZ-04           101.0 27 42 39.30 N 69 29 20.64 E
```

I have tried <kbd>Alt+Shift</kbd> option. Also tried <kbd>Alt+C</kbd> option, but these option are for single small file. I also failed to record macro and run it.

[image]

Comment: I believe this question belongs in the superuser.stackexchange.com forum (even though I see you've tagged it `notepad++`.

Comment: This is not a job for an editor, you'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: you might also try unix.stackexchange.com using the `cat` command to concatenate your ending output.  But yes, and @Toto said.

Comment: With notepad++ regex,  this is much closer,  Find: `(O-.*?\d+\.0\K|\G)(.{2})`   Replace with:  `$2`  ↝ [`space `$2 `space `] but I'm a newbie so can't tell the engine to ignore the dot, otherwise it'll be a fixed answer

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not a good solution, but a pragmatic one. You maybe warned - please make a **backup copy** of all files first.

I assume your files all have the extension *.txt and following format and reside in folder e.g. **D:\_working**:

```
SUR AREA                 ABC
SUR NAME                 ABC 2000
SUR DATE                 2000
TAPE VERSION             N/A
BBBBBBBBBBB              ABC
LOCATION TYPE            ABC
O-XYZ-O4           101.0274239.3ON692920.64E
O-XYZ-O4           102.0274240.11N692920.65E
O-XYZ-O4           103.0274240.93N692920.66E
O-XYZ-O4           104.0274241.74N692920.67E
O-XYZ-O4           105.0274242.56N692920.67E
O-XYZ-O4           106.0274243.37N692920.68E
```

- First open one of the files in your working directory by Notepad++
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Go to the *Find in Files* tab
- Find what:`(\w{1}-\w{3}-\w{2}\s{11})(.{5})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(.{5})([N])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(.{5})[E]`
- Replace with:`\1\2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8 \9 E`
- Filters: *.txt
- Directory: e.g. D:\_working
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>
- Click on <kbd>OK</kbd> when you're really sure.

Please note the spaces in the replace string.

This is resulting in:

```
SUR AREA                 ABC
SUR NAME                 ABC 2000
SUR DATE                 2000
TAPE VERSION             N/A
BBBBBBBBBBB              ABC
LOCATION TYPE            ABC
O-XYZ-O4           101.0 27 42 39.3O N 69 29 20.64 E
O-XYZ-O4           102.0 27 42 40.11 N 69 29 20.65 E
O-XYZ-O4           103.0 27 42 40.93 N 69 29 20.66 E
O-XYZ-O4           104.0 27 42 41.74 N 69 29 20.67 E
O-XYZ-O4           105.0 27 42 42.56 N 69 29 20.67 E
O-XYZ-O4           106.0 27 42 43.37 N 69 29 20.68 E
```

If you have data for the whole globe then you have to adjust the RegEx for North, East, South and West. If the counter before the geographical coordinates exceeds 999 you have to adjust the RegEx as well.